# How to order columns in a confusion matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have a confusion matrix that looks like this:

```
[[110,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  20,    0,   0,   0,  12,   0],
[   0, 107,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  62,  12,    0,   0,   0,   1,   0],
[   0,   0,  70,   1,  10,   0,   0,   0,   0,    0,   0,   0, 213,  34,],
[   0,   0, 110,  14,  14,   0,   0,   0,   0,    0 ,  0,   0   60   55],
[   0,   0,  40,   0, 178,   3,   1,   0,   3,    7,   7,   0, 256,  31],
[   0,   0   65,  14,   3,  73,   0,   0,   0,    0,   0,   0,   4,  82],
[   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  41,   2,  242,   2,   0,   0,  75,   5],
[   2,   1,   0,   1,   0,   0,   1,  88,  112,   0,   0,   0,   1,  29],
[   3,   7    0,   2,   0,   0   78,  43,  14,   58,   0,   1,  20,  26],
[   0,   0,   0,   0,  31,   0,   0,   4,   0,  517,   0,   0, 238,   1],
[  13,   0,   4,   0,   0,   0,   2,  94, 128,    1,  49,  31, 204,  18],
[   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  11,   0,    0,   0, 184,   1,   9],
[   0,   0,   8,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   2,    0,   0,   0, 130,   7],
[   0,   0,   0    0,   0,   0    0,   0,  17,    0,   0,   0,  51, 79]]
```

The class labels are this:

```
[0,1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How do I reorder the confusion matrix so that the class labels are in order, like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try slicing:

```
new_orders = np.argsort(classes)
cm[new_orders][:,new_orders]
```